# UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext Swift iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I want to show a View - `PresentedView` over another view - `Background View` using iOS 7. In my app, I am using `UITabBArController`, so at runtime I don't know which view would be the background view (*could be any of the tab bar items*). Below is the structure:

```
UITabBarController
  ---> TabItem1 - FirstUIViewController
  ---> TabItem2 - SecondUIViewController
  ---> TabItem3 - ThirdUIViewController
```

Need something Like this:

[image]

When app loads, I am on `TabItem1 - FirstUIViewController`. When I click on `TabItem3`, I want `ThirdUIViewController` to appear on Top on `FirstUIViewController` and 'FirstUIViewController' should appear in background with no user interaction enabled.

**What I did so far:**

1. Since, `UIViewControllers` are added as `Relationship Controllers` to appear as `TabBar Item` in `UITabBarController, I added a segue from tabbarcontroller to ThridViewController.
2. Changed PresentationStyle for this Segue to UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext and did below modification

   ```
   func `viewDidLoad()` {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.performSegue("identifier", sender: self)
   }
   ```

**Nothing happens and I just see 'ThridViewController' with white background**

3. I tried manual coding approach:

   ```
   func `viewDidLoad()` {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let overlayController:UIThirdViewController = UIThirdViewController() //This controller has a view added on top of it, which covers top half screen only
       overlayController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
       self.presentViewController(overlayController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```

**No change. New view overrides the previos view. if I add this `overlayController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`, I see half screen black and half containing my new view**

***Problem Points:***

1. Where should I write the code to initialize/call ThirdViewController to appear on top of current view?
2. How to fix the black screen issue and make it work on iOS 7?

I am using Xcode 7 and running on iOS7. Please help. Working code snippet will be appreciated. Don't post other stack overflow posts as answer, unless code works & you have tried on your own.

**UPDATE:** - With this approach, I get a black screen

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        let switchController:UIViewController = SwitchViewController()

        self.presentingViewController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.CurrentContext
        self.presentingViewController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.presentViewController(switchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a Custom Container View Controller ([Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)). Working example code:

```
class MyTabVC: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        presentThirdVC()
        return false
    }

    func presentThirdVC() {
        let myThirdVC = MyThirdVC.makeVC()

        myThirdVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.1)
        addChildViewController(myThirdVC)
        var newFrame = CGRectInset(view.bounds, 0, 50) // hack, do what you want
        myThirdVC.view.frame = newFrame
        view.addSubview(myThirdVC.view)
        didMoveToParentViewController(myThirdVC)
    }

}

class MyThirdVC: UIViewController {
    class func makeVC() -> MyThirdVC {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myThirdVC") as! MyThirdVC
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I believe these APIs have been around since iOS 5, by looking at the version support for addChildViewController.

Answer (score 4):

You should subclass `UITabBarController` and add it the behaviour into the custom subclass. Set the `UITabBarController` delegate as `self` and then when the specific index is tapped instead of letting it switch tabs you modally present the menu. The `UITabBarControllerDelegate` methods will give you the chance to do that.

Specifcally using this delegate method....

```
- tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:
```

You can present the menu when this is called for which ever tab and return NO. Just you a blank viewController for this tab since it will never get shown to the user.

For the transition itself I highly recommend using a subclass of `UIPresentationController` to set the container views frame to be a bit smaller than the size of the screen, and add in a "dimmingView". This is only available on iOS8 though so if you want iOS7 you will need to do more hackish things.

Comment: Please check my **UPDATE** in description